# Gradient descent algorithm not terminating

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

Given the minimization problem

$$\underset{x_1, x_2}{\text{minimize}} \quad f (x_1, x_2) := x_1^2 + y x_2^2 - x_1 x_2 - x_1 - x_2$$

My algorithm is working fine for a specific range of $y$ and for some specific range of $y$, for example $y = -1$, my gradient descent algorithm is **not** terminating irrespective of the initial step size and initial point chosen.

I am not able to decode that why this is happening.

I tried to evaluate the Hessian matrix and for $y = -1$, it comes out to be negative. That means, this function is **neither convex nor concave**. Can this be the reason why it is not terminating?

I read about this on internet and found that gradient descent algorithm can be applied to functions in general irrespective of them being convex or concave. I also tried to print the values of function at each iteration. It seems that values are not converging rather diverging and overflow happened after millions of iterations. As I said, this is only happening when Hessian is negative. Please help!

Comment: Huh?  The RHS $X_1^2-yX_2^2-X_1X_2-X_1-X_2$ is a constant function of $(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: In the same way that $f(x)=X$ (for all $x$) or $f(\omega)=\Omega$ (for all $\omega$) is a constant function, $f(x)=x$ (for all $x$) is the identity function.

Comment: No No! The function is taking different values for different X1, X2. How are you saying it to be constant, is not clear to me?

Comment: The Hessian is [[2, -1], [-1, -2y]] with determinant -4y-1. For `y = -1` the determinant is negative, resulting in a positive and a negative eigenvalue, thus a saddle point. I am not able to decode that why my algorithm is not converging the sequence.

Comment: No! No! In $f(x_1,x_2)$ you are only allow to vary $x_1,x_2$ and not $X_1,X_2$.  The derivative is 0 since $f(x_1+h_1,x_2+h_2)=f(x_1,x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2,h_1,h_2$.

Comment: Please don't confuse with the notation of Capitalization, I mean, they are same: x1 and X1. I just edited though.

Comment: If you decide $x$ and $X$ are the same then so is $n$ and $N$ in the usual definition of convergent sequences (thus $\forall n>N$ is vacuous hence all sequences converge)  or $f$ and $F$ are the same in FTC.  I'll leave you to figure out all the consequences.

Comment: I'm literally sorry for that. I was my perspective to assume that they are same. Please help!

Comment: If your function has no minimum then why should gradient descent terminate? As it turns out for $y = -1$ your function does indeed take arbitrarily large negative values.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, but theory of Gradient Descent Alogrithm suggests that function should converge to global minima in case of strictly convex function and if function is not convex or concave i.e. having a saddle point, it should go to that. That's why I posed a doubt if it is something related to its proof of convergence and I am probably missing that. As you also correctly pointed out that minimum value doesn't exist is this case, but shouldn't it then stop at its saddle point?

Comment: In your post you refer to "my gradient descent algorithm" – if you designed it yourself, then it is up to _you_ to prove that it has the properties you claim. If you are simply implementing someone else's algorithm then perhaps your implementation is faulty, or their proof is wrong. Either way, you will need to supply more details.

Comment: If $y=-1$, the function has no minimum.  Take $x_1=0$, for example.  Then $f(0,x_2)=-x^2_2 -x_2$.

Comment: @mjw Yeah, Thanks!

Comment: If $y \le 0$, the function has no minimum.  At what values of $y$ does your algorithm/code converge?

Comment: @mjw taking y > 0.3 (I have tried this far), the function converges perfectly but for lesser values for example, y = 0.23, it doesn't, it goes to `-infinity`.

Comment: Right, your experimentation is on target.  Turns out that $y=0.25$ is a transition point in the analysis.  Please see the posted answer.

Comment: @mjw Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_1} =2x_1 - x_2 -1 $$
$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_2} =-x_1 + 2yx_2  -1 $$

So optima or saddle points could occur when both of these are zero:

$$2x_1 - x_2 =1 $$
$$-x_1 + 2yx_2  =1 $$

Computing the Hessian (the matrix of second derivatives):

$$H= \pmatrix{2 &-1\\-1 &2y},$$

we see that the Hessian is zero when $y=\frac{1}{4}$ and positive for $y>\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus, for $y>\frac{1}{4}$, a minimum will exist.  For $y<\frac{1}{4}$, the function has a saddle point and no minimum.  For $y=\frac{1}{4}$, higher order tests are required, so says https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html.